# Use global variable in specification step

Tags: getgauge

I am quite new to gauge. I am trying to test API requests. Is it possible to specify an endpoint which contains an id defined globally? E.g. a specification step like

`* Make Get Request To "/endpoint-path/${id}/value"`

I use gauge with TypeScript. I was able to achieve what I want using a workaround using the variable *id* (which is defined globally in the step implementation file or possibly in a DataStore)

`endpoint = endpoint.replace(${id}, id);`

Is there a way of really using a variable bidirectional?

My gauge version is.

```
Gauge version: 1.0.6

Plugins
-------
html-report (4.0.8)
python (0.3.5)
screenshot (0.0.1)
ts (0.0.2)
xml-report (0.2.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is not possible with Gauge